# How to access a key value pair secret from AWS Secrets Manager, in concourse?

Tags: amazon-web-services, concourse, aws-secrets-manager, secretsmanager, bosh

I have a concourse environment deployed using bosh. It is configured with AWS Secrets Manager.
The pipeline secret template is of the form `/concourse/{{.Team}}/{{.Secret}}`

I have a secret `/concourse/team1/general` created in AWS Secrets Manager (Other type of secrets) with the below value.

```
{
  "gitbranch": "master",
  "hello": "2",
  "general": "hi"
}
```

I have a concourse pipeline `hello-world.yml` set in `team1` team.

```
---
jobs:
- name: job
  public: true
  plan:
  - task: check-secret
    config:
      platform: linux
      image_resource:
        type: registry-image
        source: { repository: busybox }
      run:
        path: echo
        args: ["((general))"]
```

This pipeline outputs the value as

```
{"gitbranch":"master","hello":"2","general":"hi"}
```

But, if I change the args (last line) in pipeline to `args: ["((general.gitbranch))"]`, then, I get the below error

```
failed to interpolate task config: cannot access field 'gitbranch' of non-map value ('string') from var: general.gitbranch
```

Is it possible to access any of the key value pairs in the secret from AWS Secrets Manager, in the concourse pipeline? If yes, how to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Answering my own question.*

By creating the secret using cli with the parameter `--secret-binary`, I was able to achieve to fetch the key value pairs.

(Previously, I was creating the secret from aws console, which got created as a secret string.)

I used the below command to update my secret to create the secret as a binary.

```
b64key=$(base64 secrets.json)
aws secretsmanager update-secret \
    --secret-id  /concourse/team1/general \
    --secret-binary "$b64key"
```

I found this [using-aws-secrets-manager-with-concourse-ci](https://www.codeammo.com/article/using-aws-secrets-manager-with-concourse-ci/) and it was helpful in solving the issue.

If anyone knows a way to do this in console, kindly let me know.

Comment: Hey you found my blog post, nice! I was about to post that as an answer. The code in Concourse that reads those secrets treats all non-binary secrets as strings, and all binary secrets as JSON. That was an undocumented "feature" the last time I checked the Concourse documentation.

Comment: To answer your other question, there is no way to create binary secrets through the AWS console at this time.

Comment: @MarkB Thanks for your comment. Yes, I was able to find your blog post, and it was helpful in a timely manner.